# How to insert character before another specific character using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I need to know how to insert an asterix before an open bracket.

I am doing multiplication using javascript's `eval`, for example, `eval("2(3)")`, but I am getting the error `"unexpected input value"`.

To solve this I need the following:

```
var str = "2(3)";
```

to be changed to this:

```
output = "2*(3)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform more complex/nested multiplication you need to use this more complicated regex `(\)|\d+(?!\d)\.?)(?=[(\d.+-])` with the `replace()` function. It will work for any combination of nested brackets, as well as plus signs, negative numbers and numbers starting or ending with a decimal point:

```js
var str, output;
str = '2(3)';
output = str.replace(/(\)|\d+(?!\d)\.?)(?=[(\d.+-])/g, '$1*');
console.log(output);
str = '2(3)(-4)';
output = str.replace(/(\)|\d+(?!\d)\.?)(?=[(\d.+-])/g, '$1*');
console.log(output);
str = '((.22(33))((-44)-55.(66)+77))';
output = str.replace(/(\)|\d+(?!\d)\.?)(?=[(\d.+-])/g, '$1*');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Dear robinCTS, 
I like to learn regex but was confuse while learning regex. Do you have any nice tutorial to easily learn regex. thanks

Comment: @Vijaykarthik The site I learned about regexes, and still use if I need to check something, is https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. Another useful site is [regex101](https://regex101.com/). There you can write, debug and learn regexes all at the same time.

Comment: Yes sure, useful link. Thanks @robinCTS

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Example:

```js
var str = '2(3)'
var output = str.replace(/\(/g, '*(')
console.log(output)
```

That will output: `2*(3)`

Comment: Congratulations on your first post. A good tip when answering javascript/HTML/CSS questions is to use a code snippet. Not only does it allow others to test the code, but it allows you to debug it before posting. (Unfortunately, editing snippets isn't supported well/at all for mobile devices.) Apart from my answer ;), yours is the next best one as it works for multiple values and negative numbers as well. It is also the simplest.

Comment: Thanks @robinCTS !

Comment: I appreciate the thanks. Try not to use "thanks" only comments too often, though. See [this FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126184) for further info. The usual way to say thanks on StackOverflow/Stack Exchange sites is to upvote comments, accept answers, and when you have at least 15 rep, to upvote answers/questions. For exceptional answers you can also award a bounty (min 75 rep required).

Comment: Also note that whilst, technically, trailing semi-colons are not required in javascript, it is a very good standard practice to always include them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace()` function combined with a little regex `([0-9])\(([0-9])` :

```js
var str = "2(3)";
var output = str.replace(/([0-9])\(([0-9])/g,'$1*($2');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your answer will suit for constant value, but if the value getting dynamically how we can proceed 

For example : var str = "2(3)(3)"; or var str = "2(3)3";

Comment: Zenoo & @Vijaykarthik Plus this answer doesn't work for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the string and add the asterisk sign like this:

```js
var str = "2(3)";
var new_str = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("(")) + "*" + str.slice(str.indexOf("("));
console.log(new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var str = "2(3)";
var a = str.split('');
a.splice(1,0,"*");
a = a.join(''); 
console.log(a);
```

Works good for me :)